# Why chainid is done in assembly in UniswapV2ERC20

Tags: solidity, assembly

I am studying uniswap solidity source code and there is something i do not understand in UniswapV2ERC20 constructor:

```
uint chainId;
assembly {
    chainId := chainid
}
```

(pasted from https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2ERC20.sol)

My question is why this affectation is done in an assembly section ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you question is "why wasn't it done in pure Solidity" then the answer is that the variable `block.chainid` was added only last month to Solidity: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/10557 . Uniswap uses version 0.5.16 which was released a year or two ago.

Comment: Thanks but i do not understand the reason. If this variable was added last month, why should it be done in assembly ? Thanks

Comment: Before that it was only possible to get it through assembly. Assembly is not pure Solidity but kind of an extension